# Is there a way to reverse search for specific values, flag them and use its corresponding date under new date column?

Tags: python, data-manipulation

> Blockquote

| trade_name1 | __date1 | trade_name2 | __date2 | trade_name3 | __date3 | trade_name4 | __date4 | trade_name5 | __date5 | trade_name6 | __date6 | trade_name7 | __date7 | trade_name8 | __date8 | trade_name9 | __date9 | trade_name10 | __date10 | trade_name11 | __date11 | trade_name12 | __date12 | trade_name13 | __date13 | trade_name14 | __date14 | trade_name15 | __date15 | trade_name16 | __date16 | trade_name17 | __date17 | trade_name18 | __date18 | trade_name19 | __date19 | trade_name20 | __date20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| MM | 1/1/2021 | MM | 9/15/2022 | PM | 10/10/2022 | PM | 10/29/2022 | PM | 11/14/2022 | PM | 12/29/2022 | PM | 1/27/2023 | PM | 2/27/2023 | PB | 4/25/2023 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |
| PM | 2/17/2021 | PB | 10/10/2022 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |
| PM | 3/3/2021 | MB | 9/13/2022 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |
| JM | 3/3/2021 | PB | 3/7/2023 | PM | 4/8/2023 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |
| MM | 3/4/2021 | MB | 10/12/2022 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |
| JM | 3/4/2021 | MB | 10/21/2022 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |

> Blockquote

These are one of the import columns from my original dataset (not entire columns). I have a problem that I know how to solve theoretically but have a hard time programming for it (2 months of Python here).

In my data, there are some columns called 'trade_name1 to trade_name20' and _date1 to _date20. What I want to do here is that if the last column has a value 'PB' or 'MB' and subsequent trade_name columns are missing then flag and take the date column associated with this column and put it as a new date. If the last column value is 'MM', 'PM', or 'JM' then look if the previous column has 'PB' or 'MB' and flag it and then use the date associated with it and put it as a new date. How to approach this, please?

The output should look something like this:

> Blockquote

| trade_name1 | __date1 | trade_name2 | __date2 | trade_name3 | __date3 | trade_name4 | __date4 | trade_name5 | __date5 | trade_name6 | __date6 | trade_name7 | __date7 | trade_name8 | __date8 | trade_name9 | __date9 | trade_name10 | __date10 | trade_name11 | __date11 | trade_name12 | __date12 | trade_name13 | __date13 | trade_name14 | __date14 | trade_name15 | __date15 | trade_name16 | __date16 | trade_name17 | __date17 | trade_name18 | __date18 | trade_name19 | __date19 | trade_name20 | __date20 | trade_flag | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| MM | 1/1/2021 | MM | 9/15/2022 | PM | 10/10/2022 | PM | 10/29/2022 | PM | 11/14/2022 | PM | 12/29/2022 | PM | 1/27/2023 | PM | 2/27/2023 | PB | 4/25/2023 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . | 1 | 4/25/2023 |
| PM | 2/17/2021 | PB | 10/10/2022 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . | 1 | 10/10/2022 |
| PM | 3/3/2021 | MB | 9/13/2022 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . | 1 | 9/13/2022 |
| JM | 3/3/2021 | PB | 3/7/2023 | PM | 4/8/2023 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . | 1 | 3/7/2023 |
| MM | 3/4/2021 | MB | 10/12/2022 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . | 1 | 10/12/2022 |
| JM | 3/4/2021 | MB | 10/21/2022 |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . |  | . | 1 | 10/21/2022 |

> Blockquote

Comment: I maybe missing something, but your example output doesn't look any different than you example input.  Can you simplify your sample data and your explanation of what you want to do?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for the lengthy columns. The example output has extra flag columns at the end. I want to create flags based on the logic explained above.

Comment: As I said before your expected output looks exactly the same as your input, so I don't understand what you are trying to do, and your explanation doesn't help because I don't know what is a 'last_column' and your sample doesn't show what is a missing trade_date or give an explanation that can be understood.

Comment: So from right to left if we encounter either 'PB' or 'MB values then flag it and create a new date column and bring the associated date value. If from right to left, we encounter 'JM', 'MM', or 'PM' values, then search if the next column has 'PB', or 'MB' values and flag it and bring its date under the new date column.